# how to schedule task every minute in c# blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

i need to schedule a work every minute, actually, i need to compare a datetime of file to see if its a new one and if so i use the data of this file to fill another excel file

i find some ideas with timer exemple and its worked well with just a console.writeline for the exemple but when i ask for a bigger thing to do like what i said, its not working....

```
Startup.cs
  in the Configure() method

            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
          try
            {
                string filePath = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\Ressources\mydatafile.txt"}";
                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
                var titrecolunTest = lines[0].Split('\t');

                foreach (var titrecolon in titrecolunTest)
                {
                    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(titrecolon.ToString()));
                }

                foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
                {
                    var cols = line.Split('\t');

                    DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
                    for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < cols.Length; cIndex++)
                    {
                        dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
                    }

                    tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
                }


                string fileNameTEST = @"wwwroot/Ressources/Template.xlsx";
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileNameTEST);
                using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheetData = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];
                    worksheetData.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, false);
                    //mettre number format sur les collones AC AI AJ AK AL AM AN

                    int nbrRows = worksheetData.Dimension.End.Row;

                    foreach (var cell in worksheetData.Cells["AI2:AN" + nbrRows])
                    {
                        cell.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
                    }

                    foreach (var cell in worksheetData.Cells["AC2:AC" + nbrRows])
                    {
                        cell.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
                    }
                    worksheetData.Cells["AI2:AN" + nbrRows].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";
                    worksheetData.Cells["AC2:AC" + nbrRows].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";

                    pck.Save();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Comment: What's not working? You need to narrow down the problem to get any help.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras , i need first to know if iam on the good way for what i need to do... 
also when i said its not working it mean that the work dont happen every minutes, and when i debug it make just one loop ...

Comment: Ideally a web app would be entirely stateless and not interact with files at all. What are these Excel files and what is happening with them? Can the data be persisted and manipulated via a more appropriate mechanism (i.e. a serverless function or separate persistence API)?

Comment: @DanielMann its just about trigering something to do... i mean, put a trigger when i get a new file data to go do that.... and all the thing that do inside the try catch is already working but when i put it inside the timer its not working

Comment: @KhalidAb I'm not saying you *can't* do it. I'm saying you *shouldn't* because it's bad architecture. If this is a toy app that's one thing, but if this is a real enterprise app that's going to be used at scale in your organization, you should ensure that it's architected properly.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for your advise. It will be used at scale for sure but i get your advise, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find a solution by using HangFire, there are nugets for it and some youtube tuto to show how it work.
really easy to use !